# Is there an Iphone key logger for non-jail broken phones?

Tags: iphone, virus

I would like to know if a key logger can be installed on a non-jail broken IPhone?

Thanks

Comment: No one has discovered how in the last 3 days.  But who knows, maybe they will in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any known cases on devices running ios9 with out a jail break?

Comment: You've posted 2 questions regarding this topic so you must really be worried that someone has access to your iPhone. Or, you're planning on eavesdropping on someone else's iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

In the practical sense, yes you can. You can use an exploit for the iPhone software to gain access to install the keylogger. If you want me to tell you how, I can't/won't.

On the nitpicky "theoretical" side - no, you cannot. If you use an exploit for the iPhone to gain access to install the keylogger, you could say that you have really jail-broken the iPhone. Thus you cannot install a keylogger on a non-jail broken iPhone.